# POSIX condition variables VS Win32 Event Objects (about spurious wakeup problem)

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, locking, condition-variable, spurious-wakeup

In POSIX, because of "spurious wakeup" problem, programmers are forced to use `while()` instead of `if` when checking condition.

I think spurious wakeup is unintuitive and confusing problem, but I thought it's an inevitable problem.

Recently, I found that event objects of win32 doesn't have "spurious wakeup" problem.

Why POSIX system and other systems still use condition variable which has "spurious wakeup" problem? (despite this can be solved?)

Comment: Spurrious wakeup is a return from a wait on a CV even though that CV was not signaled.  This does happen, but it is very rare.  A much more likely situation that robust code needs to accommodate is that a thread returns from its wait after the CV *was* signaled, but the associated predicate is nevertheless false (at least by the time that the thread actually returns).  This can be entirely natural under a variety of circumstances.  Putting your CV wait inside a loop would still be the right thing to do without the possibility of spurrious wakeup.

Comment: I'd note, too, that [Win32 event objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/event-objects) _contain their own predicate_, viz., the "state" that is either "signaled" or "nonsignaled."  You could easily, POSIXly construct your own `struct my_event` (with a condvar, mutex, and flag) and a `my_event_timedwait(struct my_event *, struct timespec *timeout)` which hides the predicate-testing-loop and is thus suitable for use in an `if` conditional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ask:

> *Why POSIX system and other systems still use condition variable which has "spurious wakeup" problem? (despite this can be solved?)*

Basically, it's faster than the alternative.

The RATIONALE section of the POSIX.1-2017 treatment of `pthread_cond_broadcast` and `pthread_cond_signal` specifically has this to say about ["Multiple Awakenings by Condition Signal"](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cond_signal.html#tag_16_418_08_01):

> While [the "spurious wakeup"] problem could be resolved, **the loss of efficiency for a fringe condition that occurs only rarely is unacceptable**, especially given that one has to check the predicate associated with a condition variable anyway. Correcting this problem would unnecessarily reduce the degree of concurrency in this basic building block for all higher-level synchronization operations.

Emphasis added.

The text further observes that forcing "a predicate-testing-loop around the condition wait" is a more robust coding practice than the alternative, because the application will necessarily tolerate superfluous broadcasts and signals from elsewhere in the code.